# How to receive webhook response to incoming messages on Twilio SMS Service

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api

I'm using the Twilio API to create a [Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api) that will send SMS. The Service should have its own unique webhook endpoint to receive replies (incoming SMS).

```
var service = ServiceResource.Create(
       friendlyName: Campaign.SMSCampaignDisplayName,
       usecase: "marketing",
       stickySender: true,
       useInboundWebhookOnNumber: false,
       inboundRequestUrl: new Uri($"<my site>/Admin/twilio/receive/{Campaign.SMSCampaignGuid}")
);
var message = MessageResource.Create(
       body: Campaign.SMSCampaignBody,
       from: new PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
       to: new PhoneNumber(Campaign.SMSCampaignTo),
       messagingServiceSid: service.Sid
);
```

The Service is created and the SMS is successfully sent. In the Twilio console I can see the service has the correct webhook URL:

[image: webhook]

But when I respond to the SMS, the webhook is not sent. In fact, the incoming message no longer appears in the Twilio console's **Monitor > Messaging** logs. Note that webhooks and incoming SMS logging was working fine when I was *not* using a Service and the incoming SMS webhook was defined on the sender phone number.

What am I missing, or is this some issue with Services? Do I need to [add a Sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api/phonenumber-resource#create-a-phonenumber-resource-add-a-phone-number-to-a-messaging-service) to the Service even though it's sending fine? How do I get the `phoneNumberSid`?

## Edit

I'm dumb, I could have just tested adding the phone number to the Service manually. That indeed did work, but I need to do it programmatically. I'm not having much luck finding the API/endpoint to get the correct `phoneNumberSid` for [this call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api/phonenumber-resource#create-a-phonenumber-resource-add-a-phone-number-to-a-messaging-service), does it not exist?

Comment: Just a quick note as I think you've discovered everything you need and Alan's answer below shows you where you can get the phoneNumberSid. When you send a message using the `messagingServiceSid` parameter, you do not need to include a `from` parameter. The Messaging Service should be in charge of which number to send from.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the IncomingPhoneNumber resource, as documented below, to get the Phone Number SID.

[List all IncomingPhoneNumber resources for your account](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource)